# NLog Refuse to Throw Exception

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, nlog, throw

Hello dear developers,

I encountered a weird problem with NLog,
I had a crash, but couldn't find a trace for the user activity in the logs.

i assume, Logging is not working...
tried searching for permissions problems and such, but all seems to be O.K.

I want to debug my logging in-case of problems so i created the following
code to tell the user if it failed to create anything:

```
public static class Log
{
    static Log()
    {
        try
        {
            AppLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("Megatec.EngineeringMatrix.AppLogger");
            ChangeLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("Megatec.EngineeringMatrix.ChangeLogger");
            DRCLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("Megatec.EngineeringMatrix.DRCLogger");

            if((AppLogger == null) || (ChangeLogger == null) || (DRCLogger == null))
                throw new NLogConfigurationException("Configuration does not specify correct loggers");
            writeStartupLogEntry();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), @"Failed to load `Megatec.EngineeringMatrix` Loggers.");
            throw;
        }

    }

    public static readonly Logger AppLogger;
    public static readonly Logger ChangeLogger;
    public static readonly Logger DRCLogger;
```

with the following configuration file:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwExceptions="true">
    <targets>
      <target xsi:type="File" name="AppLogFile" createDirs="true" fileName="c:/log?s/${processname}/${logger}_${shortdate}.log"
              layout=">> ${time} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

      <target xsi:type="File" name="ChangeLogFile" createDirs="true" fileName="c:/log?s/${processname}/${logger}_${shortdate}.log"
              layout=">> ${date} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

      <target xsi:type="File" name="DRCLogFile" createDirs="true" fileName="c:/logs/${processname}/${logger}_${shortdate}.log"
              layout=">> ${date} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="Megatec.EngineeringMatrix.AppLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="AppLogFile" />
      <logger name="Megatec.EngineeringMatrix.ChangeLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ChangeLogFile" />
      <logger name="Megatec.EngineeringMatrix.DRCLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="DRCLogFile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

*OBVIOUSLY* I written a BAAD config because a directory `c:\lo?gs` cannot be created.

but still, i don't get the message
`MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), @"Failed to load 'Megatec.EngineeringMatrix'`

and even `AppLogger.Info()` skips the exception...

nothing i written to log, but the App don't know it...

In debug, i can catch the exception, and see it is handled by NLog,

How can I catch it from my code?

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting steps here:  http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file#Troubleshooting_logging ?  By default, logging exceptions are swallowed.

Comment: yes, i added the necessery config parameter as you can see..
but still.  i can see in the internalLog, but not passed to the application.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue, but there are some recent changes on this.

Some exceptions were 'eaten' by NLog in the past. For example in the `AsyncWrapper` (or using the attribute `async` on `<target>`)

This has been fixed in NLog 4.3:

> Consistent handling of exceptions (BEHAVIOUR CHANGE)
>   The logging and throwing of exceptions was previously inconsistent. Not all of it was logged to the internal logger and some times they got lost. For example, the async wrapper (or async attribute) was catching all exceptions without a proper rethrow.
>
> This is bad as it is sometimes unclear why NLog isn’t working (got it myself multiple times). This has been fixed in NLog 4.3!
>
> All exceptions are logged to the internal logger
>   The “throwExceptions” option will be respected in all cases
>   Advise: disable throwExceptions in production environments! (this the default)

see http://nlog-project.org/2016/04/16/nlog-4-3-has-been-released.html